# ADC Timing Problems in FPGA design

Tags: adc, fpga, clock, timing

I am using a Xilinx Kintex UltraScale FPGA (AXKU040 development board) and an ADC board (FL9616 board). I would like to have a design that provides the ADC data as a data stream inside the FPGA. The current design has an asynchronous FIFO that receives the ADC data and outputs the data to my FPGA design as a stream of data (wr_en and rd_en from the FIFO are always true).

The problem is that when my whole FPGA design is scaled up, the ADC clock (250 MHz clock coming from the daughter board) shows unstable behaviors. Sometimes it seems to have many glitches and it messes up my data and timing. But when I use an independent 250 MHz clock the problem is solved!

The following pictures are evidences showing the ADC clock have problems!

[image]

As you can see in the image above, the clock coming from the ADC is scrambled over a period of time!

or,

[image]

As you can see in red box, the write_count data in FIFO increases suddenly! But we expect increase one in each clock!

Now I'm asking for help to solve this issue! What should I check and what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

What you are seing on that wave form could come from several source.

If the PLL unlocks, it could show a similar behavior.on many pll, you can have a signal for pll locked. I would check it to see if it is the issue. It is also possible that an other PLL fails. So i would check all the plls.

An other possible issue would be a mislead of the signal you are seeing. Logic analyzers are notorious for hiding analog issues. For example,  if the clock amplitude was to drop, you could also see weird clocking issue. If you have an oscilloscope, try to measure your clock.